# How can I get the list of all actions of MVC Controller by passing ControllerName?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, action

How can I get the list of all actions of Controller?  I search but cannot find example/answer.  I see some example recommended using reflection but I don't know how.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
public List<string> ActionNames(string controllerName){




}
```

Comment: I'm going to put a comment here, because it's general. For what you're trying to do (controller action names) is not the way that it should be done. There may be several actions with the same name and some may be Ajax only etc etc. Your permissions should be based on other things than controller actions.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You haven't told us why you need this but one possibility is to use reflection:

```
public List<string> ActionNames(string controllerName)
{
    var types =
        from a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        from t in a.GetTypes()
        where typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t) &&
                string.Equals(controllerName + "Controller", t.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        select t;

    var controllerType = types.FirstOrDefault();

    if (controllerType == null)
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>().ToList();
    }
    return new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(controllerType)
        .GetCanonicalActions().Select(x => x.ActionName)
        .ToList();
}
```

Obviously as we know reflection is not very fast so if you intend to call this method often you might consider improving it by caching the list of controllers to avoid fetching it everytime and even [memoizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the method for given input parameters.

Comment: Thank You!!! In my application, I need to create permission page for admin user. Admin would select a controller name from from dropdownlist, then the actionlist would dynamically display based on selected controller name. Then assign those value to users/roles.

Comment: I got the error on "from t in a.GetTypes()-Unable to load one or more of the requested types."

Comment: It's worth pointing out that ReflectedControllerDescriptor's GetCanonicalActions method will return an ActionDescriptor for every public method on the controller, including methods that aren't actions. It also ignores the NonActionAttribute.

Comment: Doesn't work when an action is decorated with a custom `[ActionName]`

Answer (score 0):

A slight tweak to Darin's answer.  I needed this change to get this to work with code lense as it runs under a different assembly.

```
public static List<string> GetAllActionNames(string controllerName)
{
    var controllerType = Assembly.Load("YourAssemblyNameHere")
        .GetTypes()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(x) 
            && x.Name.Equals(controllerName + "Controller", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

    if (controllerType == null)
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>().ToList();
    }
    return new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(controllerType)
        .GetCanonicalActions().Select(x => x.ActionName)
        .ToList();
}
```