# How to get all url available for views/partial views or to controler action in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created an asp.net MVC 3 project. This project has around 200+ webpages (Views/Partial views). Listing all these links one by one will be very time consuming and tedious. So now I want enlist all link available in this project automatically on single view, so that admin(user) will have access to all links available for respective users.

Here question arises, How to get all url available for views/partial views or to controller action in asp.net MVC?

I was trying asp.net MVC route table. but I think I was trying in wrong direction.

Comment: Are these views virtual or real cshtml files?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583278/getting-all-controllers-and-actions-names-in-c-sharp) shows how to get all the controllers and action methods

Comment: these are real .cshtml files.

Comment: Link was not helpfull, it is 0 links in array.

Comment: @PranavLabhe, Its not returning 'links'. Its an example of how you can retrieve all the controller and action names necessary to build you links in a simple `foreach` loop using `@Html.ActionLink("action", "controller")`

Comment: i tried this  .. '@{
    System.Reflection.Assembly asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var arr = asm.GetTypes()
.Where(type => typeof(Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type)) //filter controllers
.SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods())
.Where(method => method.IsPublic).ToList();
}'

Comment: but , var arr came with 0 items