# Determine at run-time available actions on a Controller (handles ActionName attribute)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I've seen several similar questions (but none wrt to the ActionName attribute) and the answers [(like this one)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21583402/1943691) use Reflection. However, what it doesn't handle is if the action method has an `[ActionName]` applied to it. So if we have something like

```
[ActionName('Profile')]
public virtual ActionResult AccountProfile(...)
```

I won't see the method name as `Profile` but rather `AccountProfile` when using similar code as shown in the linked solution. For our use case, that's no good.

We're currently using MVC5.

Comment: With reflection you can get attributes for method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  IList<string> actionNames=new List<string>();
    Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    var methodInfos = asm.GetTypes()
        .Where(type => typeof(Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type)) //filter controllers
        .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods())
        .Where(method => method.IsPublic &&method.CustomAttributes.Any(a=>a.AttributeType==typeof(ActionNameAttribute)));
    foreach (var methodInfo in methodInfos)
    {
        var actionAttribute =
            methodInfo.CustomAttributes.First(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(ActionNameAttribute));
        var actionName = actionAttribute.ConstructorArguments.First().Value;
        actionNames.Add(actionName.ToString());

    }
```