# Context menu for ASP.NET MVC 5 missing for automatically generated views and controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created an ASP.NET MVC5 project with vs2017 Community, and generated the controllers and views automatically via an entity, however the views are not added to the menu bar/context menu. I checked the GUIDs in the project file and they seem to be correct when matched against [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs). The default GUIDs from my project:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Below is the menu bar that I received

[image: Menu bar at the top of the project]

The default `body` code in the Shared Layout:

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                <p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">Hello, @User.Identity.Name!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

How do I get the views to be added by default to the menu?

Answer (score 2):

You need to alter this part of the code:

```
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
```

to add the other menu entries that you expect to see.

If you want it more automated, check out https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1130643/Auto-Generate-Menu-from-Controllers-in-ASP-NET-MVC or [Getting All Controllers and Actions names in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583278/getting-all-controllers-and-actions-names-in-c-sharp) .

Comment: Thanks. I thought that this was already a default feature in this type of project.

Comment: Alas, no. You have to build it.

Answer (score 0):

Under the `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">` you should add the additional links to your views. Like below:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "Action Name", "Controller Name")</li>
```