# Is it possible to loop through controller names in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to make a simple `foreach` loop with existing controller names in a simple WPF.

For example I have these:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Label3" Text="Vasalás" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="LanguageSelectorCombo" Grid.Column="3" Margin="40 0 40 0" SelectedIndex="0" SelectionChanged="LanguageSelectorCombo_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Options1" Foreground="Black" Text="Hungarian"/>
    </ComboBoxItem>
```

Here I would like to get `Label3`, `LanguageSelectorCombo` and `Options1`.

Comment: Why would you loop if you can access it directly from the x:Name directive?

Comment: I'd like to compare them with another list.

Comment: give this a try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583278/getting-all-controllers-and-actions-names-in-c-sharp/36443722

Comment: @Daniel thank you, I'll give it a try ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting All Controllers and Actions names in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583278/getting-all-controllers-and-actions-names-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is simple foreach loop. You will need to use [LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(parentControl)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598654.aspx) recursively to get all children controls. [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) might also help you to get specific child control.

Comment: Thanky you, this might be a good way to start.