# How can I get full url of all Actions in api controller

Tags: c#, url, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller that should return full urls of the other Actions in the same controller. I dont know how I can do this. Please look at my example (using pseudo results):

```
[Route("api/v{api-version:apiVersion}/Tests")]
[ApiController][AllowAnonymous]
public class TestsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetActions()
    {
        var idDemo = 1;

        //TODO         
        urls.Add("Get full url for Call method with parameter : idDemo ");
        urls.Add("Get full url for Something method with parameter : idDemo ");

        return Ok(urls);
    }

    [HttpPost("call/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Call(int id)
    {
         return Ok();
    }

    [HttpPost("do/it/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Something(int id)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: what you want has already been done in a much more useful way:  Swagger

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the list of all actions of MVC Controller by passing ControllerName?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300327/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-all-actions-of-mvc-controller-by-passing-controllernam)